# Javascript: Is the length method efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

i'm doing some javascript coding and I was wondering if the length method is "precomputed", or remembered by the JS engine.

So, the question is:

If I'm checking really often for an array length, and supposing that i'm not changing it (making it immutable through a closure), should I precompute the length method and store it in some variable?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no `length` **method** in built-in javascript objects, but accessing object property is often slower than accessing local variable.

Comment: Why's that @Pointly? Can't i look for every improvement in my code? Can't I just be curious?

Comment: It's fine to be curious, but it's also important to write (as Joe Armstrong from the Erlang world calls it) "beautiful code".  Sometimes, such little "optimizations" can backfire when JavaScript implementations introduce new optimizations intended to speed up code written with common idioms.

Comment: So, if the array computes its length everytime the .lenth method is called (I don't know this, that's why i'm asking here) and I store 1000000 objects in it, that would be a "little" performance penalty? I agree with you with the readability, but don't want to kill my users browser neither.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All major interpreters provide efficient accessors for the lengths of native arrays, but not for array-like objects like [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList)s.

["Efficient looping in Javascript"](http://solutoire.com/2007/02/02/efficient-looping-in-javascript/)

> ```
> Test / Browser                Firefox 2.0 Opera 9.1   Internet Explorer 6
> Native For-Loop               155 (ms)    121 (ms)    160 (ms)
> ...
> Improved Native While-Loop    120 (ms)    100 (ms)    110 (ms)
> ```

["Efficient JavaScript code"](http://userjs.org/help/tutorials/efficient-code) suggests

> ```
> for( var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length; i++ ) {
>   document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].className = 'newclass';
>   document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].style.color = 'red';
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
> for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
>   rows[i].className = 'newclass';
>   rows[i].style.color = 'red';
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> Neither of these are efficient. `getElementsByTagName` returns a dynamic object, not a static array. Every time the loop condition is checked, Opera has to reassess the object, and work out how many elements it references, in order to work out the `length` property. This takes a little more time than checking against a static number.

Comment: Is that true for all `NodeList`s, or just live ones?

Comment: Thanks @Mike, do you have some code? Maybe a derived question would be: "How are arrays implemented in Javascript?"

Comment: When I look at Mozilla's developer network for arrays I don't see much information provided for length https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array But, I would precompute the length and store it in a variable just to be safe. I don't think the browsers share the same JS engine

Comment: @amnotiam, Are there non-live `NodeList`s?  My guess would be it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @santiagobasulto, JavaScript arrays are implemented differently.  It really depends on how aggressively they `realloc` to avoid copying or splitting chunks, and how they deal with large sparse arrays `var arr = []; arr[1e6] = true;`.  For small dense-arrays, you can think of them as contiguous blocks of memory.

Comment: @S.P. You are correct.  Browsers do not share the same JS engine.  Microsoft has a few now.  Mozilla has TraceMonkey.  Safari and Opera use JavaScriptCore.  Chrome uses V8.

Comment: Methods like `querySelectorAll` return a non-live NodeList. I would assume it would be precomputed, but then I never thought about the live lists being computed on the fly before. Makes sense. I usually cache the `.length` anyway unless I'm anticipating some mutation during the loop, so I guess I never really thought about it before.

Comment: @amnotiam, Ah, I see in [Selectors API Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), "The NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll() method must be static, not live ([DOM-LEVEL-3-CORE], section 1.1.1). Subsequent changes to the structure of the underlying document must not be reflected in the NodeList object. This means that the object will instead contain a list of matching Element nodes that were in the document at the time the list was created."

Answer (score 32):

As always, the answer is "it depends".

[Let's test native arrays with a million-element array:](http://jsperf.com/array-length-performance)

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++);

var len=arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++);
```

http://josh3736.net/images/arrlen.png

Chrome and Firefox optimize the property accessor to be as efficient as copying the length to a local variable.  IE and Opera do not, and are 50%+ slower.

**However**, keep in mind that the test results' "ops/second" means number of *complete iterations through an array of one million elements* per second.

To put this in perspective, even in IE8 (the worst performer in this bunch)—which scored .44 and 3.9 on property access and local variable (respectively)—the per-iteration penalty was a scant **2 µs**.  Iterating over a thousand items, using `array.length` will only cost you an extra 2 ms.  In other words: **beware premature optimization**.

Comment: Saving 2 ms for 1,000 items is not premature optimization. As more, what if there are 10,000 items? If the code is frequently called?

Comment: You should've posted the image on Stackoverflow and not on your personal website, which is not available anymore...

Answer (score 21):

The length of an actual array is not computed on the fly.  It's stored as part of the array data structure so accessing it involves no more work than just fetching the value (there is no computation).  As such, it will generally be as fast as retrieving any fixed property of an object.  As you can see in this performance test, there is basically no difference between retrieving the length of an array and retrieving a property of an object:

http://jsperf.com/length-comparisons

An exception to this is the nodeList objects that the DOM returns from functions like `getElementsByTagName()` or `getElementsByClassName()`.  In these, it is often much slower to access the length property.  This is probably because these nodeList objects are not true javascript objects and there may be a bridge between Javascript and native code that must be crossed each time something is accessed from these objects.  In this case, it would be a LOT faster (10-100x faster) to cache the length into a local variable rather than use it repeatedly in a loop off the nodeList.  I've added that to the length-comparison and you can see how much slower it is.

In some browsers, it is meaningfully faster to put the length into a local variable and use it from there if you will be referring to it over and over again (like in a loop).  Here's the performance graph from the above jsperf test:

[image]

Comment: To add more about `length` being a property and not a function, the ECMAScript 2015 Language specification describes `Array.length` as "a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every configurable own property whose name is an array index." https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a modest speed boost attainable by caching the length in a local variable due to attribute lookup speed. This may or may not be negligible, depending on how the JS engine JITs the code.

See http://jsperf.com/for-loop-caching for a rudimentary JSperf testcase.

Comment: Thanks @AKX, I don't consider attribute lookup a problem. Using array.length keep things readable.

Comment: Here is a not-so-rudimentary jsperf test case http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4

Comment: Good tests! I'm not iterating over it though. I'm just using it's modulus to cycle it.

Answer (score 2):

For any collection-type object whose length you will not be manipulating (e.g. any immutable collection), it's always a good idea to cache its length for better performance.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName("tst");
var elemsLen = elems.length;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < elemsLen; ++i)
{
  // work with elems... example:
  // elems[i].selected = false;
}
elems = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100];
elemsLen = elems.length;
for(i = 0; i < elemsLen; ++i)
{
  // work with elems... example:
  // elems[i] = elems[i] / 10;
}
```

Comment: Why? Any Code? I think it's better to use the .length method, if there is no performance penalty. I mean, if it's not computed every time i call it.

Comment: @santiagobasulto You are correct that the 'length' property is not always calculated and thus does not cost performance on some browsers. However, on other browsers, caching to a variable is faster than accessing the 'length' property in a loop. See http://jsperf.com/for-loop-caching for more proof. Then scroll down and notice that IE and Opera perform better when caching the 'length' value instead of accessing it via the property within a loop.