# ag-grid sorting is not working with another third party plugin

Tags: sorting, ag-grid, stimulsoft

ag-grid sorting is not working with another third party plugin. 
Stimulsoft report.js for reporting tool.

[please find plunkr link for the same.](https://plnkr.co/edit/U8UrxUzwIpLob5olfBq7?p=preview)

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@13.3.1/dist/ag-grid.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stimulsoft-reports-js@2018.2.3/stimulsoft.reports.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no idea what your actual question is. The demo doesn't help. Try to explain what problem you're having. Are you getting an error?

Comment: in plunk sorting on ag-grid doesn't works. due to due to adding stimulsoft report.js. if you remove or  comment this line then it works
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stimulsoft-reports-js@2018.2.3/stimulsoft.reports.js"></script>

Comment: I see what you're saying. The sorting does *sometimes* work though, you really have to have click around a lot and you can find instances where it doesn't work. For example, the "Age" column always works for me. You have to be specific, "ag-grid sorting is not working" is too vague. Include exact steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ag-grid

```
      ComponentUtil.toNumber = function(value) {
            if (typeof value === 'number') {
                return value;
            } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
                return Number(value);
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        }
```

and in stimulsoft

```
Object.prototype.toNumber = function() {
   if (this.sti_is(String) && this.indexOf(",") >= 0)
      return Number(this.replaceAll(",", "."));
   return Number(this)
}
```

so due to this conflict sorting is not able to do.

then i added below lines then solved my issue.

```
<script>
     Object.prototype.toNumber = undefined;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely due to the fact that "Stimulsoft Reports.JS" heavily modifies the native prototypes (`String`/ `Array`/`Object`, at least) in JavaScript, which is almost always a terrible idea.

Their code is bad, in other words.

Here are some supporting links:

- [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)
- [Why is it frowned upon to modify JavaScript object's prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223449/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-modify-javascript-objects-prototypes/6223471)
- http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/

As for how to fix it, no idea. It's a long investigation to figure that out.

Try putting the Stimulshaft stuff in a `iframe` so it can be nice and happy alone to pollute itself.

I'm not even *certain* that this is the cause, but it probably is. It might be that there's something ag-grid can do to fix it on their end, but it's not their problem. Whatever is happening, it's Stimulshaft's fault.

Comment: can we get exact issue then we can convey them (stimulsoft). because i had already issue with base64 class and now they solved from their end.

Comment: If you send them a link to this Stack Overflow question (with some additional explanation), they should be able to figure it out. That is, if you're a paying customer and they're willing to put in the time. It's all the `Array.prototype.add=function`/`Object.prototype.toNumber=function` stuff in their code.