# JS Classic Fibonacci Challenge - Differences between two solutions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two solutions to the same challenge, this classic fibonacci challenge that everyone knows how to solve it (even your pets).

I kindly ask you NOT to suggest any other solutions.
I just want to compare these two solutions. Thousands different solutions can be found with searches.

**Challenge:**

```
/*
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9 
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]

     fib(3) returns 2
     fib(9) returns 34
     and so on...

*/
```

Both solutions below are working fine. My only question is:

Does **solution B** run slower than **solution A**? Because in **B** we have this line below:

```
fibArr.push(fibArr[fibArr.length - 1] + fibArr[fibArr.length - 2])
```

Does the `length` function go through the entire array to calculate the number of items? Or already returns from immediately?

**Solution A**:

```
function fib(n) {
  const fiboArray = [0,1]
  for(let i=2; i <= n; i++) {
    fiboArray.push(fiboArray[i-2] + fiboArray[i-1])
  }
  return fiboArray[n]
}
console.log(fib(5))
```

**Solution B**:

```
function fib(n) {
  const fibArr = [0, 1, 1]
  
  if(n == 0) {
    return 0
  }

  if(n == 1 || n == 2) {
    return 1
  }


  if (n > 2) {
    for (let i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
      fibArr.push(fibArr[fibArr.length - 1] + fibArr[fibArr.length - 2])
    }
  }
  
  return fibArr[fibArr.length - 1]
}


console.log(fib(9))
```

Comment: Yeah, not extracting the `.length` each time could make it imperceptibly faster, but it's almost certainly not a bottleneck

Comment: otherwise it is still a bit silly to recalculate the 2 index positions at each loop round instead of simply keeping the last 2 sum for the next iteration

Comment: @MisterJojo can you please show me a code example to simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with CertainPerformance, Solution A is better.

In many situations using .length would be just as fast because the browser will pre-compute it and go just as efficiently as if you make a local variable yourself however I think in your case Solution A is better because you use push on the array during the loop so length will be recalculated.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592241/javascript-is-the-length-method-efficient) post talks about it but he doesn't have push like you do.

Answer (score 1):

> @MisterJojo can you please show me a code example to simplify it?

```js
function my_Fibonacci(n)
  {
  let a = 0
    , b = 1
    , r = [0, 1]
    ;
  for(let i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
    r.push(a+b) // new fibonacci value
    a = b       // set a for next addition
    b = r[i]    // set b for next addition
    }
  // return r.join(' - ')
  return b
  }

document.write(my_Fibonacci(9))
```